# What does "failed services loaded" mean in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, systemd, services

What is this "failed services loaded"?

How do I check which services failed?

```
Services loaded: 232 active: 231 failed: 1 
Ubintu 18.04.3
Kernel 5.2.8
```

Comment: Use a standard 18.04.3 kernel, like 5.0.0, not 5.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**systemd : List failed Services**

```
systemctl --state=failed
systemctl -a | grep failed
```

**systemd : List all Services**

```
systemctl -a
```

**[systemctl manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/systemctl.1.html)**

Comment: systemctl --state=failed
  UNIT               LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                   
● ureadahead.service loaded failed failed Read required files in advance

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.

Comment: systemctl -a | grep failed
● ureadahead.service                                                                                           loaded    failed   failed    Read required files in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try systemctl list-units --state=failed. This will tell you if any systemd controlled components have failed.

Also journalctl -b0 -p 3. This will list errors since the start of the latest boot